# bada app that Always in run

Tags: bada

I want to write an application that check incoming SMS for Spm blocking. how to be notified of the recieved SMS in my App? how to be always in run in bada OS?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that it is possible presently...

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not supported until current bada sdk v2.x

An excerpt from bada doc [link](http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.documentation.help/html/bada_overview/bada_app_model/multitasking_in_bada.htm):

{
    ...when multiple bada applications are running simultaneously, only one bada application can run in the foreground while the remaining applications run in the background...
}